# Access to like-or-dislike feature through youtube api

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, youtube-api

I have an asp.net application where users can upload videos to youtube, view the uploaded videos and vote for a video if they wish. All the above except the voting part is working.

I had a look at the sample code in the youtube api dot net developers guide:
video.Rating = 5;
request.Insert(video.RatingsUri, video);

but keep on getting an error saying I need to authenticate. If i authenticate its works fine.

My question is my do I need to authenticate when I add a rating(like/dislike) for a video through the api but if you go to www.youtube.com you can rate(like/dislike) a video without logging into your personal youtube account first?

What do I need to do to add a rating to a video without authenticating first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the API at:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Ratings

In section "**Adding a rating**" it says:

> To add a rating to a video, send an
>   authenticated POST request to the
>   video's ratings URL. The user who is
>   rating the video must be identified by
>   the authentication token.

It looks like you must authenticate a user when you use the API. Even when it is possible to rate withouth login as a normal user using a browser. Maybe some API limitation to prevent abuse.

Comment: all my research up to now is saying the same as you. i was wondering if by any chance there is a workaround or solution for this problem.

Comment: As it looks it's not a "problem" but a design decision of the YouTube API. So I hardly doubt that there is any workarround when using this API.