# Why do the buttons users could click at the end of embedded YT videos not appearing?

Tags: youtube-api, social-media-like

Only the subscribe button appears at the end (along with a display of how many likes/dislikes checked direct on YT). Is there an embed code to get these back so users can vote on my site?

Sample embed code:

```
<object style="height: 360px; width: 640px">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXXXXXXXX?version=3&controls=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&iv_load_policy=3&border=2&color1=0xB24D7E&color2=0xfff0f5&fs=1&hd=0&feature=player_embedded" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allownetworking" value="internal" /><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXXXXXXX?version=3&controls=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&iv_load_policy=3&border=2&color1=0xB24D7E&color2=0xfff0f5&fs=1&hd=0&feature=player_embedded" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" allownetworking="internal" width="640" height="360"></embed></object>
```

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521125/access-to-like-or-dislike-feature-through-youtube-api) for related discussion.

Answer (score 0):

- **Embedded AS3 player**
  .If you open http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE?autoplay=1,
  it's equivalent to AS2 player,
  http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE?autoplay=1&version=2

  However, if you only open http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE without parameters(such as autoplay), http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE no more version 2, it's version 3 now.

  You need version 3(AS3) for display likes/dislikes icon, that's means
  http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE?version=1234567 or
  http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE?version=3

  You open http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE, play at the
  end, you copy the embed code, unfortunately the embed code is wrong,
  it give you

> name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
>   src="http://www.youtube.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3"
>   type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true"
>   allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360">

As you can see, no **question mark ?** inside
   **http://www.youtube.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3**
   , thats means its still version 2, you shoud change to
   http://www.youtube.com/v/_Acr-FWRWXE?hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3
   instead.

- **IFrame embed**.
   Using www.youtube.com/embed/a6_AHH-A0ks

Hope this help :)